# tensorboard logdir with s3 path

Tags: amazon-s3, tensorflow, tensorboard

I see tensorflow support AWS s3 file system (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/core/platform/s3) but I am unable to use the S3 path with tensorboard.

I tried latest nightly `0.4.0rc3` but no luck. I built locally also and made sure `Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Amazon S3 File System support? [Y/n]:` set to `YES` but still i don't see `tensorboard --logdir=s3://bucket/path` working at all.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3):

If you start a tensorboard by using AWS s3 file, you should do as follows:

(1) add ENV VARIBLES

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=******
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=*******
export S3_ENDPOINT=******
export S3_VERIFY_SSL=0    
export S3_USE_HTTPS=0
```

(2) upgrade tensorflow to newest version by using pip:

```
pip install tensorflow==1.4.1
```

(3) you don't need to upgrade tensorboard, because it is revolved in the previous step

Then you can start you tensorboard by using you code

```
tensorboard --logdir=s3://bucket/path
```

Comment: What you really missed here is the region of s3 bucket which seems to be manditory to look for s3 bucket...tensorboard does not show an error if i miss it but it does not load anything....ex:`S3_REGION=us-east-1 tensorboard --logdir=s3://bucket/path` Not sure if `S3_ENDPOINT` env can address this.

Comment: In case this still doesn't work, then please try `pip install boto3`