# Tensorboard with S3 location

Tags: tensorboard

I am trying to use S3 path with `tensorboard --logdir` command and getting the below error:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnimplementedError: File system scheme 's3' not implemented (file: 's3://bucket/repo/dummyExperiments')

It is not working for me even after setting S3_REGION in environment variables.
*My tensorboard version is 1.7.0.*
Command used : `tensorboard --logdir=s3://repo/dummyExperiments`

I tried to get some input from the post [tensorboard logdir with s3 path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47425882/tensorboard-logdir-with-s3-path) but it was not very helpful.

Does tensorboard support S3?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Tensorboard does support S3.

I created an EC2 instance and installed tensorflow 1.7 on the ubuntu machine.
Initially I was getting error 'Curl error code 6' on running tensorboard with S3 location.
But later I installed old tensorflow version 1.5 and it worked even without setting any environment variables.

Somehow the latest 1.7 version is not compatible with S3 and throws error.

NOTE: Before `tensorboard --logdir=s3://repo/dummyExperiments` , make sure that your server is connected to S3.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022 Jan 19, [this is fixed](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/5480#issuecomment-1016612630). You will need to `pip install tensorflow-io` for it to work.

In the past, this used to work out-of-the-box, but for about the last year or so reading tboard logs directly off S3 has been broken.